# How to interact between a ROS snap and a Clearpath Jackal?

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, clearpath, jackal

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am planning to install my ROS package as a `Snap` on a `Clearpath Jackal`. How would I do this in a way that would allow the nodes within my `Snap` to publish and subscribe to topics available from the `Jackal`?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/364310/how-to-interact-between-a-ros-snap-and-a-clearpath-jackal?/) by [Py](https://answers.ros.org/users/48264/py/) on ROS Answers with karma: 501 on 2020-10-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kyrofa](https://answers.ros.org/users/20478/kyrofa/) on 2020-10-28**:
I'm unfamiliar with the Jackal. Are you going to be installing the snap on the same machine as the rest of the ROS software? Or another that is on the same network?

**Comment by [Py](https://answers.ros.org/users/48264/py/) on 2020-10-29**:
I plan to install the snap on the Jackals SBC, which runs the rest of the ROS software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you're installing the snap to run alongside the rest of the ROS software, on the Jackal's SBC, the snap should "just work" and be able to publish and subscribe to topics available from the Jackal by connecting to the Jackal's rosmaster. Snaps don't operate in a nested/NAT'd network namespace, you just need to make sure the snap uses the `network` and `network-bind` plugs to be able to properly access the network under confinement and it sees your host's network interface just like any other application.

If for some reason the Jackal uses a non-standard port for rosmaster, you can change where the snap connects by defining the `catkin-ros-master-uri` option in the snapcraft.yaml's catkin part.

---

Originally posted by [kyrofa](https://answers.ros.org/users/20478/kyrofa/) with karma: 347 on 2020-10-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Py](https://answers.ros.org/users/48264/py/) on 2020-10-29**:
Thats great! Thanks very much for the help.